# Converting an NFA to DFA

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, graphing-functions, automata

I am atttempting to convert an NFA into an equivalent DFA. I did it, but i am not sure if it is correct. If anyone can please take a look at let me know if it is correct or if there is something wrong with it, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

(Note:I just realized i have 2 {q1,q2})

UPDATED VERSION:
[image]

Here it is:[image]

Comment: Does the symbol $\lambda$ in the transition $q_0 \to q_1$ correspond to the empty string?

Comment: Yes, that is the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you look at the transition from $q_1$ with the symbol $0$, then it can go to $q_1$ as well by using the empty transition after passing through $q_0$ first.  The DFA you've written down doesn't accept "00", which is accepted by the NFA above.

You also need, as mentioned in the other answer, to make the start state $\{q_0, q_1\}$, since that empty transition means that that the empty string is accepted, since it is accepted by the NFA.

Comment: I edited it, can you check it again?thank you.

Comment: @user655321 the transition from state $\{q_1, q_2\}$ with symbol 0 should go to $\{q_0, q_1, q_2\}$, since $q_1$ can go to any of the three states with input 0.  Otherwise, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

If lambda is the empty string then that isn't correct. Remember the start state is the epsilon closure of the start state - in other words the start state should be the union of q0 and q1

*note I havent done NFA to DFA in awhile so correct me if im wrong.